# Zabbix Log file monitoring for specific word

Tags: zabbix

the log that is mentioned here, will have the word alive or not and if the word alive is missing for more than the interval (30s), then it should alert.

I need to check what changes needs to be done to make sure the alert is triggered if the word alive is missing for more than 30 seconds?

Comment: What OS is on the system you're having this file?

Comment: Could you be more specific explaining your setup?

Answer (score 1):

First make a script that will watch the logfile ( `while :; sleep 30; ...` ) and can call a function when `alive` is missing. Use zabbix_sender for alerting Zabbix.
Alternatively you can send a message every 30 seconds to Zabbix and make a trigger in Zabbix when it is silent, but that will cause a lot of communication (do not save historical data here).